# Detect when user changes tabs

Tags: ms-access, events, vba

[image: tabs]

How do I detect when the user changes tabs in Access? In VBA hopefully, and not as an Office Add-In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms and Reports are Access objects that have `Activate`/`Deactivate` events that can trigger VBA when a they get/lose the focus. Clicking on the "Net Worth Summary" in your image would fire MainMenu's `Form_Deactivate()` and NetWorthSummary's `Report_Activate()` events. Tables and queries don't have events like this that you can trap, just forms and reports.

Comment: I used OnFocus. Thanks.